# Applying Cayley's Theorem to $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Cayley's Theorem states, every group G is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group acting on G. I also know the dihedral group $D_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. But I was wondering, is it because of Cayley's Theorem we know $D_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ (Does Cayley's Theorem guarantee that $D_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$?)?

Comment: I see why Cayley's Theorem is not need, but could you still say Cayley's Theorem guarantees that $D_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$?

Comment: You would be able to guarantee that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, it depends on how you initially define $D_{2n}$ as to whether it IS a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of $D_{2n}$ by its geometric action, it is the group corresponding to the reflections and rotations of an $n$-gon. Each of these reflections and rotations is a bijection on the vertices of our $n$-gon. So we get that $D_{2n}$ is (at least isomorphic to) a group of bijections on $n$ elements, i.e. a subgroup of $S_n$.

As you can see, we haven't used Cayley's Theorem anywhere in this explanation.

Notation: I use $D_{2n}$ to be the dihedral group with $2n$ elements. I'm just pointing it out because others (as I'm assuming you do) use $D_n$ because it acts on an $n$-gon. Both are valid I just have a preference for $D_{2n}$, that's the only reason I used it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the description of $D_n$ as symmetries of an $n$-sided polygon then you can see that it naturally permutes the vertices of that polygon giving a realization as a subgroup of $S_n$, no Cayley's thoerem is needed. (Actually that theorem would say $D_n$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{2n}$ of order $(2n)!$. 
Dihedral group is generated by the fundamental rotation which is a cyclic permutation of length $n$ on $1,2,\dots, n$ and any reflection.

A convenient reflection would be the one passing through the mod-point the first and last vertex: $v_1$ and $v_n$ It would be swapping simultaneously the $k$th vertex from the first with the $k$th vertex from the last.

So $D_n\subset S_n$ is the subgroup generated by the cycle
$(123\quad  n)$ and $(1,n)(2,n-1)(3,n-2)\cdots$

Comment: Cayley says a group of order $r$ is a subgroup of $S_r$, so I think it is an exclamation mark, and not a factorial.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: That stupid mistake has been corrected.